# Android Studio building issues - Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

While building android app, Attached the issue i’m facing. [Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtpAj.png)

Below is the project level gradle file i'm using.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried with gradle build tools versions(**4.0.2, 4.1.0**), still getting the same issue. '**Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration**'
I’m using
**Android Studio 4.1.2**, working on **always on VPN** in windows machine, Before this(always on VPN) it used to work for me. Somehow this is not working now. Could some one help me one this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this :

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

Comment: what would be the value of this? -> $kotlin_version

Comment: that is the kotlin version you need to use, i edited the answer, you can check

Comment: Hi @nidhi, tried the above suggestion. still getting the same issue. Could you have any idea it might be an issue with always on VPN. which is not able to download the required dependencies.

Comment: @SanathBoyina, i dont think it could be because of vpn, 
 in app level gradle, have you mentioned this : 
`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'`

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application' it's there in app level gradle file. apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' this is not there because we are not using anything from kotlin. it is not required as we are not using anything from kotlin.

Comment: in the screenshot you added, it says kotlin resource not found.